# Python Function parameters and arguments

Tags: python, function, parameters, arguments

I want to understand functions and arguments better, I've read and this is my implementation of what I have read.

I have 3 small functions to illustrate my point.

User input collection,
grading function and
main.

```
def score(num1: int):
    print("Please Enter Your Score: ")
    num1 = int(input())
    grade(num1)


def grade(num1: int):
    if int(num1) in range(0,30):
        print("Grade U")
    if int(num1)in range(30,40):
        print("Grade D")
    if int(num1)in range(40,60):
        print("Grade C")
    if int(num1)in range(60,80):
        print("Grade B")
    if int(num1)>79:
        print("Grade A")


def main():
    print("Hi")
    score(1)
```

If I run the main function without its argument (1), it results in an error looking for the argument. I know that I declared in the function that it has a parameter (as i want this as a return value) but how would I go about calling the score function without its argument??
 E.G

```
def main()
print("hi")
score()
```

I imagine that functions are called without parameters and the arguments are passed into the parameters from the function definition (via user input)
 Can someone provide an example as to how I could do this without needing the dummy variable (1) in the calling of the score function?

Comment: Please note, that the parameter `num1` that you pass into the score function is not actually used anywhere.

Comment: Why _does_ `score` take a parameter, which it then immediately ignores in favour of user input?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I wasnt aware that it was ignoring the parameter, i thought i was telling the function it is looking for a variable which i assigned to input

Comment: @rv.kvetch it makes sense now why i had to define num1 as an int for the grade function to work on the variable. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way I would do it:

```py
def score():
    print("Please Enter Your Score: ")
    num1 = int(input())
    grade(num1)


def grade(num1: int):
    if 0 <= num1 < 30:
        print("Grade U")
    elif 30 <= num1 < 40:
        print("Grade D")
    elif 40 <= num1 < 60:
        print("Grade C")
    elif 60 <= num1 < 80:
        print("Grade B")
    elif num1 >= 80:
        print("Grade A")


def main():
    print("Hi")
    score()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you want to still be able to pass a parameter into the score function, like `score(1)`, then you can instead assign an optional parameter to the function. Then, only read user input if `num1` is not passed in to the score function.

```
def score(num1=None):
    if num1 is None:
        print("Please Enter Your Score: ")
        num1 = int(input())

    grade(num1)
```

Usage:

```py
def main():
    print("Hi")
    score(1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, its appreciated. 
To clarify, when creating the parameter for a function, the variable is passed into the function? 

I created it the way i did to pass the variable out of the function, but it looks like i do not need to do that, rather just pass the variable to another function inside the original function. Is that right?

Comment: @ChristAHFER Yes, that is correct, when you define a parameter for a function, that variable is always present within the scope of the function, and can be used as if that variable were instead defined via the assignment operator, like `x=1`. You can also inspect the `locals()` object in Python from within the function, and that will contain all variables that have already been defined, and that are local to the function itself.

Comment: For example, within a sample function, I would suggest having a line like `x = 2` that creates a local variable `x` and initializes it to a value, and then printing out the `locals()` on the next line, so that it's easier to see what local variables are available within the function scope.

Comment: That's a very handy function, thank you